# Atmega328 and max485 schematic problem

Tags: rs485

i'm making atmega328 and max485esa in one pcb.
first build using an external 5v dc source and without any problems. the code works fine, the ws2812 led on the receiver module can light up.
the second time I added a regulator 7805,  led didn't turn on, I checked there was nothing short,
to make sure I made a new pcb by separating the atmega and max485 ground and the results  still not working.
can anyone help?.
Why schematic doesn't work.
Thank you.
[![max485][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvRPA.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvRPA.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGFcu.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: `led didn't turn on` ... are you talking about D1?

Comment: Led ws2812 on receive module

Comment: @jsotola i think it's "led on the receiver module" and the schematic is obviously TX-only

Comment: @Ecvary I don't see any bus termination on the schematics

Comment: @Ecvary also, what is the point of reverse polarity protection (if that what it is) _after_ the LDO?

Comment: A 7805 can hardly be described as a LDO! Q2, Q3 and the associated zener and resistor are superfluous. Why were they ever included? R8 and 9 are just plain silly. Why does it not work? i ‘d be checking to see the micro has been programmed correctly.

Comment: @Kartman You realize that considering the meaning of the question the drop out of the regulator is rather irrelevant? After all, you asked the same question yourself. Anyway, my bet is on termination, or rather lack of it

Comment: thank you for responding.
I'm new in electrical. I only learned the schematic from the internet, the max485 schematic I learned from dmx transmit and receive from Paul Stofferagen / oshpark sharing project. in Figure 1 and it works fine.
then i made this board and faced the problem.
after 4 failures and several leds burned, I tried to add pnp flow protection (pcb 5 / layout 1) with an external power source the scheme worked fine.
then i added 7805 ( pcb 7 / layout 2) and it failed again ( i tried to directly connect ws2812 to data pin and code worked, ws2812 led can light up).

Comment: @Maple. Sure there’s termination - R15 and C15.  I’m confused - what does the max485 have to do with a ws2812?  J5 is so wrong. I have no idea of what is trying to be achieved here. All i can see is some random circuitry that really makes little sense.

Comment: @Kartman The AC termination is only good for low data rates. I guess I should have asked about network speed before claiming that standard termination is missing. But I agree, out of 27 components on the schematics about 12 are useless

Comment: I  just realized that there is no RS485 network here, WS2812 is just a LED strip, and 485 transceiver is used as a buffer of sorts. Which means there are even more unnecessary components on the board, considering that each LED chip conditions the signal before passing it forward. Yes, this looks exactly like my first forays into electronics, when I was stacking pieces of different schematics together without understanding what I am doing. I recall being really proud of myself when it accidentally worked :)

Comment: Cancel (need more experiment)   adding regulator and replace with over voltage protection.  :)   https://youtube.com/shorts/n-A5tUb8De0